# YUI3 view events object do not fire events

Tags: javascript, events, yui3

YUI3 custom view module do not calls showPanel() function
whn the user clicks to  the Y.SpHeader (view) should call showPanel event handler.

the code Does not throw any error in console it simply do not work. and not logging in console that the button is clicked.

```
    YUI.add('sp-header-section', function(Y){
    Y.SpHeader = Y.Base.create('sp-header-section', Y.View, [], {
        events: {
            '#sign-up': {'click': "showPanel"}
        },

        initializer: function(config){
            this._initPanel();
        },

        render: function(){
            new Y.SpDropdownMenu({
                contentBox: "#top_menu",
                descriptions: true
            }).render();        
        },

        // Private Methods
        _initPanel: function(){
          var okButton = this.okBotton;
          var cancelButton = this.cancelButton;
          this.panel = new Y.Panel({
                width: 300,
                centered: true,
                headerContent: 'Sign Up To Recieve a Book',
                bodyContent: 'CAUTION: Watch out for random panels.',
                zIndex: 999,
                modal: true,

            });  
        },

        showPanel: function(){
            Y.log('the button is clicked');
            this.panel.reder();  
        },

        // Panel Buttons Configurations
        okButton: {
            value: 'ok',
            section: Y.WidgetStdMod.FOOTER,
            action: function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                this.hide();
            }
        },

        cancelButton: {
            value: 'cancel',
            section: Y.WidgetStdMod.FOOTER,
            action: function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
                this.hide();
            }
        }
    }, {
        ATTRS:{    
        }
    }); 
},'1.0', {requires: ['sp-dropdown-menu', 'panel', 'escape', 'view']});   


YUI().use('sp-header-section', function(Y){
    var header = new Y.SpHeader({}).render();
});
```

Comment: "Y.SpDropdownMenu is not a function" but I am sure I need more "context" - can you try to create a simple JSfiddle?

Comment: It seems like you have multiple errors. please create a jsfiddle or runnable example. Your main problem is that your `showPanel()` function calls [`this.panel.reder();`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Panel.html#method_render) [sic] when it should call [`this.show()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Panel.html#method_show). **Note:** You should call `render()` somewhere to initialize the `panel` in the DOM, but after that you should just use `show()` and `hide()`.

Comment: I guess you need to specify the container of the view...